# Move activeadmin queries to different database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, master-slave

We are using activadmin plugin to manage our app dashboard. We want to move some of the dashboard queries to a different db connection(slave) to reduce load on master.
Is there any way to redirect the queries coming from active admin dashboard to different db connection.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just split models between databases (for example, model1 and model2 data located only in database1, and `activeadmin` models data located only in database2), you can define location in model class.

You need to do:

- Add second database description to `/config/database.yml`

```
secondary_db: # db identifier
  adapter: sqlite3 # change to your database
  timeout: 5000
  pool: 5
  database: db/activeadmin.sqlite3
```

- Define database in model files

```rb
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection 'secondary_db' # use db identifier from database.yml file
  ...
end
```

- And move your data if neccesary

Look [establish_connection in rails documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/establish_connection/class)